# apache solr response does not return result

Tags: postgresql, solr

i conntected apache solr with my postgresql database i tried to retrieve result set using this url

```
 http://localhost:8055/solr/dataimport?command=full-import
```

this is db-data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://myhost:myport/addressbook" user="username"  password="password"/>
      <document>
        <entity name="addressbook" 
            query="select firstname from addressbook where firstname like '%A%'">
             <field name="id" column="id" />
        </entity>
      </document>
</dataConfig>
```

im getting response as this. But i couldn't see the result rows here.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <response>
- <lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int> 
  <int name="QTime">0</int> 
  </lst>
- <lst name="initArgs">
- <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str> 
  </lst>
  </lst>
  <str name="command">full-import</str> 
  <str name="status">idle</str> 
  <str name="importResponse" /> 
- <lst name="statusMessages">
  <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str> 
  <str name="Total Rows Fetched">11</str> 
  <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str> 
  <str name="Full Dump Started">2013-01-17 00:29:26</str> 
  <str name="">Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.</str> 
  <str name="Committed">2013-01-17 00:29:27</str> 
  <str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str> 
  <str name="Time taken">0:0:1.343</str> 
  </lst>
  <str name="WARNING">This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future.</str>
```

what changes should i do in db-data-config.xml to get result rows here. please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think your query should be:

- select * **[STAR]** from addressbook where firstname like '%A%'

or at least

- select **id** from addressbook where firstname like '%A%'

Currently, you seem to be selecting **firstname** but then trying to map **id**. There is no overlap there, so you get empty entries.

Comment: Or try changing `<field name="id" column="id" />` to `<field name="id" column="firstname" />`